# SQL ignoring my condition?

Tags: sql, postgresql

First time using SQL so please be patient if mine is a silly mistake.
My database has 3 tables. However for this query we are only concerned with the `ALBUM` table. For each album, it contains the year of publication, artist name, album name, album rating.

I am trying to find results where two albums are no further apart in time than a certain number of years.

This is what I came up with:

```
SELECT "ALBUM"."ARTIST" 
FROM public."ALBUM"     
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT "A"."ARTIST"    
FROM public."ALBUM" AS "A" 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
( SELECT "B"."ARTIST"
FROM 
  public."ALBUM" "A", 
  public."ALBUM" "B"
WHERE 
  "A"."TITLE" != "B"."TITLE" AND    
  "A"."ARTIST" = "B"."ARTIST" AND
  "B"."YEAR"  <= "A"."YEAR" AND 
  "B"."YEAR" +4 < "A"."YEAR"
  )   
) 
UNION
SELECT "A"."ARTIST" 
FROM public."ALBUM" "A"
WHERE NOT EXISTS
( SELECT "B"."ARTIST"
FROM  public."ALBUM" "B"
WHERE "A"."ARTIST" = "B"."ARTIST"
AND "A"."TITLE" != "B"."TITLE") ;
```

My thinking was: I first find all those artists for whom there exist at least two albums but for a given album there is no other within 4 years, and then I would subtract this group from the set of all artists. The union part is to add to my results those who only have published 1 album in total.

The code runs fine in PostgreSQL but the data returned is not actually filtered by the criteria provided so something in the code is ignored/ not working but I have been stuck on what for a while now. Any tip?

Comment: Please add sample data and output for those sample data that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Unrelated, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers.

Comment: Does the first SELECT work stand-alone? Does the second SELECT work stand-alone?

Comment: Please do **not** post sample "data" as screen shots. Post them as formatted text, or even better as `create table` and `insert` statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend 2 step approach:

1: Single self join query finding the artists.

```
SELECT "B"."ARTIST"
FROM 
  public."ALBUM" "A", 
  public."ALBUM" "B"
WHERE 
  "A"."TITLE" != "B"."TITLE" AND    
  "A"."ARTIST" = "B"."ARTIST" AND
  "B"."YEAR" < "A"."YEAR" + 4
```

2. Wrapping the first query in the `NOT EXISTS` clause as you tried to do.

   ```
   SELECT ARTIST FROM public."ALBUM" "C" WHERE NOT EXISTS    
   (SELECT "B"."ARTIST"
    FROM 
     public."ALBUM" "A", 
     public."ALBUM" "B"
    WHERE 
     "A"."TITLE" != "B"."TITLE" AND    
     "A"."ARTIST" = "B"."ARTIST" AND
     "A"."ARTIST" = "C"."ARTIST" AND
     "B"."YEAR" < "A"."YEAR" + 4)
   ```

Note that you must bind the outer and inner query of `EXISTS` with something to make it work. Further I think, your condition for year comparison was reversed.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach combining CTEs (Common table expression) and window functions could be as follows:

```
with single_album as 
    (select artist, count(artist) as albums 
     from album 
     group by artist),
    album_year_delta as
    (select 
        artist,
        album_year,
        (album_year - 
        lag(album_year,1)
        over(partition by artist order by album_year)) as year_difference
    from album)
select 
    artist 
from single_album 
where 
    albums=1
union
select
    artist
from album_year_delta
where year_difference > 4;
```

1. First you identify the single album artists with a simple count
2. Calculate the time interval between each album release year
3. Specify your selection criteria

Note: I simplified the naming convention for clarity as the double quotes and table prefixing was somewhat heavy.
Hope this helps.